# Which driver has to be selected for Nvidia Geforce GT 520 from list?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm a rookie to the Ubuntu. I'm having Nvidia Geforce GT 520 graphics card. In the additional drivers, it shows a lot of drivers in which some are proprietary and some are not.

[image: additional driver image]

So please help me to choose the correct one for mine? Eager to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Choose `nvidia-352`. This is the correct proprietary driver for your adapter.

Comment: Screen shot shows all the available legacy drives. You can check if older nVidia card which version is correct. But do not install from nVidia directly use Ubuntu repository or newer Ubuntu ppa for drivers. Legacy drivers by GPU model 
http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html
Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers
Ubuntu "Fresh" Proprietary Driver PPA, only use is extremely new nVidia card and need newest drivers. https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: +1 to get you out of the Low Quality review queue: short, simple, correct answer.